# Ordering values from the same field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need help:

I have the following Table.

```
      P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6
John   1  2  3  4  5  7
Paul   2  7  5  1  4  3
Mony   7  6  5  4  3  2
```

One name is one suscriptor who already registered on the webpage, and therefore, one name is one field.

When the suscriptor is logged in, he has to arrange those variables (P1, P2, P3 and so on), and after that he clicks the "save" button, and those values are saved within the mysql table. Until here it works fine.

The problem is that I need the order arranged from the suscriptor when he refreshs the page. I've been thinking of using "SELECT FROM ORDER BY" but this is for when you want to order some fields. Here I have only one field from which I want to arrange those values.

I don't know if I've explained it well. I hope so.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you show us the expected result?

Comment: yep I don't get it.  You could unpivot the data (case & unions) and sort but then you get name, Label and value as columns  you could sort by the value but then the labels are unordered.  What you're trying to do in the database seems like a UI function.

Comment: For example, if John orders the atributtes in this way P1 = 2, P2 = 3, P3 = 1 (those values are saved within the MYSQL table) when he refreshes the webpage, this order has to be respected.

Comment: Teh issue is order is something you apply to a column individually.  You're trying to apply order to multiple columns per user.  This could be done by `Select Label, Value FROM (SELECT name, P1 as Value , 'P1' Label from table u nion all SELECT name, P2 as Value , 'P2' Label from table u nion all ...) B Where name = 'John' order by value.`

Comment: Oh, I am gonna try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize the data using unions (unpivot the data)

```
SELECT Label, P
FROM (Select Name, P1 as P, 'P1' as Label from table union all 
      Select Name, P2 as P, 'P2' as Label from table union all 
      Select Name, P3 as P, 'P3' as Label from table union all 
      Select Name, P4 as P, 'P4' as Label from table union all 
      Select Name, P5 as P, 'P5' as Label from table union all 
      Select name, p6 as P, 'P6' as Label from table ) Z 
WHERE Z.Name = 'Paul' 
ORDER BY P
```

which would give you

```
P4 1
P1 2
P6 3
P5 4
P3 5
P2 7
```

and then if needed you could pivot it again based on the values.. However,  order of the COLUMNS returned is irrelevant when you can grab specific fields by name in the result set.... so this really doesn't make much sense.

But all of this seems for naught as what you're trying to do I believe is better suited for the UI not the database.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that it will be better if I try to do so with the UI, because there are a lot of values. Thank you.

Comment: @AlvaroLópezSánchez In case you hadn't already grasped the point, this is (almost) how the data should be stored to begin with - a database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.